# Possible "Children of the Corn" sequel with four teenagers in an attic

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, telekinesis

Can anyone identify this movie based on this trailer I remember from the '90s?

Four teenagers in an attic. Two of them appear to be evil and pressuring the good kids to join them in their cause. They seem to be exerting some kind of telekinetic force on them, for one of the kids, a girl, says, "Stop, you're hurting us!" as she clutches her temple in pain. I also recall a man's voiceover explaining the plot: a town threatened by evil kids, save a few remaining good ones (I was young when exposed to this trailer, so my impression might be a bit fuzzy).

I am almost certain this was a *Children of the Corn* sequel, but I have not been able to find any such trailer or any plot synopsis matching my recollection.